# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: flex2/tools/oem/PathResolver while building swc through maven

Tags: java, maven, apache-flex, adobe, flash-builder

I am building an Flash builder app with flash sdk 3.6.0 and I am getting this error while building swc in maven. please help me to solve this?

```
    import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]

-----------------------------------------------------

        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:166)
        ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: flex2/tools/oem/PathResolver
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2595)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:1914)
        at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.forConstructorOf(InjectionPoint.java:245)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl.create(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:99)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createUninitializedBinding(InjectorImpl.java:658)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:882)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBindingRecursive(InjectorImpl.java:805)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:282)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getBindingOrThrow(InjectorImpl.java:214)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProviderOrThrow(InjectorImpl.java:1006)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider(InjectorImpl.java:1038)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider(InjectorImpl.java:1001)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1051)
        at org.eclipse.sisu.space.AbstractDeferredClass.get(AbstractDeferredClass.java:48)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:81)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:53)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call(ProviderInternalFactory.java:65)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:115)
        at org.eclipse.sisu.bean.BeanScheduler$Activator.onProvision(BeanScheduler.java:176)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:126)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:68)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:63)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:45)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:1016)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1092)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1012)
        at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.Guice4$1.get(Guice4.java:162)
        at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue(LazyBeanEntry.java:81)
        at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.LazyPlexusBean.getValue(LazyPlexusBean.java:51)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:263)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:255)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:517)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:121)
        ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: flex2.tools.oem.PathResolver
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:271)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:247)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:239)
        ... 55 more
[ERROR]
```

here is the pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>FlexCommon</groupId>
    <artifactId>FlexCommon</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>swc</packaging>
     <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.sonatype.flexmojos</groupId>
        <artifactId>flexmojos-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.0</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.adobe.flex.framework</groupId>
      <artifactId>flex-framework</artifactId>
      <version>4.5.1.21328</version>
      <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>

   <!--  <dependency>
      <groupId>com.adobe.flexunit</groupId>
      <artifactId>flexunit</artifactId>
      <version>0.85</version>
      <type>swc</type>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency> -->
  </dependencies>

  <profiles>
    <profile><!--https://docs.sonatype.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=2949459-->
      <id>m2e</id>
      <activation>
        <property>
          <name>m2e.version</name>
        </property>
      </activation>
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.maven.ide.eclipse</groupId>
            <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.9-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <configuration>
              <mappingId>customizable</mappingId>
              <configurators>
                <configurator id='org.maven.ide.eclipse.configuration.flex.configurator' />
              </configurators>
              <mojoExecutions>
                <mojoExecution>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin::</mojoExecution>
              </mojoExecutions>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <pluginManagement>
          <plugins>
            <plugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>2.4</version>
            </plugin>
          </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
      </build>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
  <repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>flex-mojos-repository</id>
    <url>http://repository.sonatype.org/content/groups/flexgroup</url>
</repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
<pluginRepository>
    <id>flex-mojos-repository</id>
    <url>http://repository.sonatype.org/content/groups/flexgroup</url>
</pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

Please let me know how to resolve this.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

try adding this

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.flex.flexjs.compiler</groupId>
  <artifactId>flexjs-compiler-parent</artifactId>
  <version>0.8.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

Comment: same issue exists

Answer (score 0):

i used with 3.8 plugin with maven 3.3.2 it worked.